# Text prediction in Linux while typing like on Android, iOS and Windows

Tags: linux, text-processing, keyboard, autocorrection, natural-language

I have noticed the utility of this feature while typing on Android devices (notably with Gboard virtual keyboard)

[image]

The same is available on iOS, in iPhones and iPads.

I don't mean the use of a virtual keyboard on Linux, but the presence of a "suggestion strip" on the screen, as it is called in Gboard, while typing in Linux, no matter the virtual or physical character of the keyboard.

Is this possible to have that with any text editor or at least some of them?

Windows 10 already has that [it seems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/enable-text-suggestions-for-inclusive-classrooms-8ca3ea32-66b1-4d9d-abf1-1d0ead34f2a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That feature is an application of neural NLP (natural language processing). Many of state of the art models are behind paywall (e.g. GPT-3), and the open source alternatives are very resource-hungry (e.g. GPT-J requires at least NVIDIA RTX 3090 to run smoothly). So TLDR: not yet!